# "No such file or directory" error with both file in same directory AND when using absolute path

Tags: python

all. I'm running into a "no such file or directory" issue in python that's stumped me.

Things I've tried so far:

- Closing any program that I could think might have the file open
- Having the file in the same directory as the program I'm running
- Using the absolute path name
- Escaping the backslashes
- Escaping the backslashes and spaces
- Changing the backslashes to forward slashes
- Removing all spaces, special symbols, and numbers from the filename

I even checked with os.getcwd and os.path.abspath and copy-pasted the path exactly.

I'm not sure what's going on here. I'm at a loss now. Would I get this same error if the file is still open in some elusive background program?

This is the relevant bit of code:

```
print(os.getcwd())
print(os.path.abspath('RainyGenki.json'))

deckName = "C:\Users\myName\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\KanjiDrag\RainyGenki.json"
deck = open(deckName, 'r')   #opens card deck
```

This is the error message:

```
C:\Users\myName\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\KanjiDrag
C:\Users\myName\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\KanjiDrag\RainyGenki.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myName\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\KanjiDrag\kanji_drag\kanji_main.py", line 79, in <module>
    deck = open(deckName, 'r')   #opens card deck
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\myName\\My Documents\\LiClipse Workspace\\KanjiDrag\\RainyGenki.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using a raw string...

If you are **sure** that your path is *OK* then use the python syntax for a raw string:

> In plain English: String literals can be enclosed in matching single
> quotes (') or double quotes ("). They can also be enclosed in matching
> groups of three single or double quotes (these are generally referred
> to as triple-quoted strings). The backslash () character is used to
> escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as
> newline, backslash itself, or the quote character. String literals may
> optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are
> called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash
> escape sequences. A prefix of 'u' or 'U' makes the string a Unicode
> string. Unicode strings use the Unicode character set as defined by
> the Unicode Consortium and ISO 10646. Some additional escape
> sequences, described below, are available in Unicode strings. A prefix
> of 'b' or 'B' is ignored in Python 2; it indicates that the literal
> should become a bytes literal in Python 3 (e.g. when code is
> automatically converted with 2to3). A 'u' or 'b' prefix may be
> followed by an 'r' prefix.

This basically means that to escape the `backslash` escape sequences, you just need to put an `'r'`before the string like:

```
deckName = r"C:\Users\myName\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\KanjiDrag\RainyGenki.json"
ck = open(deckName, "r")
```

And even though you say you have tried it, escaping the backslashes should also work:

```
deckName = "C:\\Users\\myName\\My Documents\\LiClipse Workspace\\KanjiDrag\\RainyGenki.json"
ck = open(deckName, "r")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that gave me the same error. I'm not sure what else to check in this case. I even did deckName =
 (os.path.abspath('RainyGenki.json') to try and eliminate any copy-pasting mistakes. Still nothing. I'm starting to think something is off with the way my editor is set up. I'm using LiClipse with pydev. I've never been so out of luck when trying to open a file in a program.

Comment: Try with just a `.txt` file in the same directory to see if that works...

Answer (score 0):

I had a folder called KanjiDrag, and within that I had the actual source folder kanji_drag which is where the json file and the main module were. The path I was using was accessing the KanjiDrag folder, but not the kanji_drag folder, and I didn't catch the different names. This is my dumbest file IO mistake yet. Thanks for all the replies, many of which I'll still refer to later when I refine this part of my program.